# import sdk to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I've looked all over stackoverflow, google, xda, etc.  But Can not seem to find out how to add an sdk to my android studio project.  I'm trying to use the 500px-android-sdk, but every time I try to import it in my main activity file, android studio doesn't recognize it.  I'm getting errors like it can't be found.

MainActivity.java:

```
import com.fivehundredpx.api
```

Which is currently not importing correctly

In settings.gradle

```
include ':myapp'
include '500px-android-sdk'
project('500px-android-sdk').projectDir = new File('libs/500px-android-sdk')
```

and my build.gradle is empty as I just cleaned it.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this SDK was created before Android Studio came out. Perhaps adding a gradle build file that sits in the same directory as the SDK's `AndroidManifest.xml` will solve the problem?

Here is my best guess as to what the `build.gradle` would look like.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+',
        compile files (
            'signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar',
            'signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar'
        )
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Android studio makes an build.gradle file in the appProject and app directory.  Which one should I put my dependencies in after I add a build.gradle file to the sdk?

Comment: You know, I just went through creating an Android Studio project, cloning the 500px SDK, and trying to get this to work, and all I have to say is: Android Studio is a steaming pile. It's not ready for commercial use yet. I would stick with IntelliJ until Android Studio has been refined more.

Comment: Thats exactly how I'm starting to feel, I've spent countless hours trying to get this to work.  Thanks for your help though.

Comment: If you have any questions about doing this with straight IntelliJ, let me know. It should be super-simple.

Comment: @lostAstronaut Did this answer actually work? Please don't mark it as the answer unless it did.

Comment: No but switching to intellij did in a just a few seconds.  So that advice did, but I can take away the answer.

Comment: Yeah, you might as well :)